# Using multiple conditions in where clause of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, operators, where-clause

I have a table called `finalres` in my database which has list of statuses and accounts.

I want to pull the accounts where the status should not be in:

```
(xxx, ina, nfc)
```

Also I want to pull the accounts where the status in `RWD` but only when account# is null. I wrote the below query but it only giving result for either one condition. please help me.

```
select *
from finalres
where 1 = 0
   or (status = 'rwd' and account# is null)
   or status not in ('xxx', 'ina', 'nfc')
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show example data *(both source data and query results)* that demonstrates both what you want to happen and what's going wrong with your current query.

Comment: what do you mean by 1 = 0 in your where clause ?

Comment: @Farshad So that developers can add conditions after and/or easily, instead of spending time to find where to add `where` statement. It's just for the convenience.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from finalres where 
(status='rwd' and account# is null) 
 or  status not in ('xxx','ina','nfc')
```

You can check this query at link below:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/11b3d/2

```
 CREATE TABLE finalres
(
  [account] int,
  [ItemNo] varchar(32),
  status varchar(100)

) 

INSERT INTO finalres (account, ItemNo, status) VALUES
  ('1', '453', 'xxx'),
  ('2', '657', '34'),
  (null, '657', 'rwd')
  ;


account     ItemNo  status
2            657     34
(null)       657     rwd
```

Comment: it still not working.it works only the first condition

Comment: @unnikrishnan can you please put some data of your table

Answer (score 0):

You have your list of statuses (xxx, ina, nfc) that you do not want records with. In addition, you only want records with a status of RWD when the account# is null, which means you need to add that status to you list of statuses that you do not want. That give you a query like this:

```
select
    *
from
    finalres
where
     status not in ('rwd','xxx','ina','nfc')
  or (status='rwd' and account is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `status not in ('xxx','ina','nfc')` allows the result to include any `status`='rwd', even if the `account#` is not null. This makes the `(status='rwd' and account# is null)` redundant. You will need to include the 'rwd' in the `status not in` query.

```
select 
*
from finalres
where 1 = 0
or (status='rwd' and account# is null)
or status not in ('rwd','xxx','ina','nfc')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
    select * 
      from finalres 
     where (status='rwd' and account# is null) 
        or status not in ('xxx','ina','nfc')
```

Comment: If `status = 'rwd'` then `status not in ('xxx','ina','nfc')` is redundant.  That's like saying `x=4 AND x NOT IN (1,2,3,5,6,7)`, you already know x is 4, so it can't be any of the other values.

Comment: `(X AND Y) AND Z` is functionally identical to `X AND Y AND Z` is functionally identical to `X AND (Y AND Z)` is functionally identical to `(X AND Z) AND Y`, etc, etc, etc, etc.